# Entity Framework Core ApplicationDbContext DI in instances created from a HostedService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have a hosted service called StateMachineHost that I create like this (in Startup.cs):

```
services.AddSingleton<StateMachineHost>();
services.AddHostedService<StateMachineHost>(provider => provider.GetService<StateMachineHost>());
```

The StateMachineHost then starts by reading the database of how many StateMachines it shall create. This is done by injecting IServiceScopeFactory

```
public StateMachineHost(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
```

and then getting an ApplicationDbContext via DI like this:

```
using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
var itemRepository = new ItemRepository(dbContext);
```

Further down in that using statement I go on and create N amount of StateMachines. Each StateMachine will need to also access the database via an ItemRepository. The question is now, how do I dependency inject ApplicationDbContext into my StateMachines? The StateMachine want to access the database at any other given point (triggered from an WebApi call and/or Timer-Tick).

My StateMachineHost stores each StateMachine in a List meaning that the StateMachine instances live throughout the application lifecycle.

In the WebApi/Repository pattern, the ApplicationDbContext gets easily injected via ASP.NET Core in the Controller constructor. But since my StateMachine has its own state and logic, I don't understand how I should create/DI the ApplicationDbContext. As I understand, both the ApplicationDbContext and Repostitory should be re-created for each database access. Meaning that I would also like to encapsulate that code somehow in my StateMachine, otherwise it will be a lot of duplicate code everywhere simply creating an ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling the constructors directly if you are using DI.  The container has a resolve method that will inject the dependencies into the constructor for you.  `container.Resolve<ItemRepository>()` What are you using for dependency injection?

Comment: But I am manually creating the StateMachine instances from my StateMachineHost instance (created via HostedService).

Comment: Manually creating instances is not really DI.  You use DI so that the consumer of your StateMachine doesn't need to worry about implementation details like dependencies.  You should read about constructor injection.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you simply registering your context (if you use `AddDbContext` extension, this will be done implicitly) and your repo as scoped services?
Inject the context in the constructor of your repo and get the repo from the service container similar to what you did...

```
using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
itemRepo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IItemRepo>();
}
```

As you create a scope for each StateMachine, you will get individual instances just out of the box...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I get the scopeFactory inside of my StateMachine? The snippet you wrote above, do I need to write that then each time I want to access the database? i.e. each time I should create a repo.

Comment: Hmm, just like you did... If I get you right, you want to implement the StateMachines as HostedServices... In there you just get the ScopeFactory DI injected. I guess it should be registered by default (like IServiceProvider)...